# In Winforms, how do you pass the datagridview row right-clicked on to the ContextMenuStrip?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, contextmenustrip

I need to know which row is right-clicked on for the contextMenuStrip in a datagridview.  Winforms, c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int id = (int)YourGridViewName.SelectedCells[0].Value;
```